# what is the difference between the type of nil and the type of type of nil in lua?

Tags: lua

```
> print(type(X))
nil
> print(type(type(X)))
string
> print(type(nil))
nil
>
```

Why are the last two prints having different results?

Comment: `assert(type(nil) ~= nil and type(nil) == "nil")`

Comment: Thank you! Really informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` of the `type` of anything will be a string because `type` always results in a string.

See: https://www.lua.org/pil/2.html

Comment: the type of nil is nil though.

Comment: @kkxx the type of `nil`is `"nil"` (which is a string) not `nil`